# Uploading files larger than maximum request length

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added a File Upload Control to my website but when I add a large file, I got this error:

`The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.`

I searched and found a suggested solution was to add this code in the web config

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="512000000"/>
```

and to edit the IIS application host Config and add this code to it

```
<maxAllowedContentLength="512000000"/>
```

I made all of these steps and it did not work. I still cannot upload a file larger than the max size.

Comment: How big is the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: Are you using .net 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS6 you need to set the following in your Web.Config (kilobytes and default is 4096 which is 4 MB):

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="4096000" />
</system.web>
```

If you are using IIS7 or later (in bytes and default is 30000000 which is almost 30MB):

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4096000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Make sure you don't add these tags if they already exist. Edit the existing ones otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Are running on dev machine? IIS Express or Cassini?
Any way thet thing is to set up your web.config.

Try this solution:

```
<httpRuntime 
executionTimeout="90" 
maxRequestLength="1024000" 
useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
minFreeThreads="8" 
minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" 
appRequestQueueLimit="100" 
enableVersionHeader="true"
/>
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10842/Setting-up-Web-config-to-allow-uploading-of-large

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you add this key under `<system.web>` and also add a attribute "execution time" as below code:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="10000"maxRequestLength="10240000"maxQueryStringLength="2097151"/>
```